# How to submit the form by Material UI Dialog using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I used the Material UI Dialog to make a form list. In the official case:

```
<Dialog
          title="Dialog With Custom Width"
          actions={actions}
          modal={true}
          open={this.state.open}
        >
          This dialog spans the entire width of the screen.
</Dialog>
```

the actions is :

```
   const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
    ];
```

How can I build a form and let Dialog can submit my form data?

------------------------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------------------------

There is another answer:

Add the attribute of `type` and `form` in the Dialog actions button:

```
const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
        type="submit"        //set the buttom type is submit
        form="myform"        //target the form which you want to sent 
      />,
    ];
```

and give attribute id to the form in the dialog:

```
<Dialog
          title="Dialog With Custom Width"
          actions={actions}
          modal={true}
          open={this.state.open}
        >
        // here can put child component and the code still work even the form is in the child component
         <div className="deal_form">
          <form id="myform" onSubmit = {this.handleCreate} >
            <TextField value={this.state.staff_number} />
          </form>
        </div>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can put a <form> inside the Dialog, but you must also put your {actions} inside the form, instead of the actions property. Your Submit action button should have type="submit" on it (type="reset" is also supported, and shown below).

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/14dugwp3/6/

```
const {
  Dialog,
  TextField,
  FlatButton,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  getMuiTheme,
} = MaterialUI;

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { open: true };
    this.handleClose = this._handleClose.bind(this);
  }

  _handleClose() {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  }

  render() {
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        type="reset"
        label="Reset"
        secondary={true}
        style={{ float: 'left' }}
        />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onClick={this.handleClose}
        />,
      <FlatButton
        type="submit"
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        />,
    ];

    return (
      <Dialog
        title="Dialog With Custom Width"
        modal={true}
        open={this.state.open}
        >
        <form action="/" method="POST" onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); alert('Submitted form!'); this.handleClose(); } }>
          This dialog spans the entire width of the screen.
          <TextField name="email" hintText="Email" />
          <TextField name="pwd" type="password" hintText="Password" />
          <div style={{ textAlign: 'right', padding: 8, margin: '24px -24px -24px -24px' }}>
            {actions}
          </div>
        </form>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme() }>
    <Example />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: If I want to let the form be a component and have a state itself, I just can use redux  to build data state ?

Comment: Yes. The component can handle state (like its open state), or you can make it a stateless function and pass "open" in as a prop (and that prop could be set by redux). Here's the above component converted to a stateless function. You could just wrap it with redux's connect() to wire it up to a store. https://jsfiddle.net/b3ahf3se/2/  good luck!

Comment: I made my form be a component `<UserForm />`,like this: `<Dialog> <UserForm/> </Dialog>`, How can I put the actions in the form?

Comment: The preventDefault prevents the form from submitting ... So this doesn't work.

Comment: Adding Submit is beneficial even if you send by yourself like JSON because you get the benefit of ENTER button to submit the form.

Answer (score 20):

In HTML5 `form=""` attribute can be used as a reference to any form on a page. So button gets `form="my-form-id"` attribute and form gets `id="my-form-id"` attribute.

```
return (
  <Dialog
    open
    actions={[
      <RaisedButton type="submit" form="my-form-id" label="Submit" />
    ]}
  >
    <form id="my-form-id" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
      <TextField {...fields.username} floatingLabelText="Username" />
    </form>
  </Dialog>
);
```

I use Material UI v0.20.

Comment: `onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}` ... ugly

Answer (score 0):

Dialog is a ui component of material ui, it will not submit your form data automatically, if you want to create a form, define it inside the Dialog like this:

```
<Dialog
      title="Dialog With Custom Width"
      actions={actions}
      modal={true}
      open={this.state.open}
    >
      /*CREATE THE FORM UI HERE*/
      <div>Field1</div>
      <div>Field2</div>
      <div>Field3</div>
</Dialog>
```

If form contains many field then use the bool in dialog to make the content scrollable `autoScrollBodyContent = {true}` .

You defined a function `this.handleSubmit.bind(this)` on submit button click, inside this function call the api and submit the data that you want to submit, once api call is success, close the dialog box.

*Please comment if this solves your issue or any other details you want.*

Comment: So how can I build the state of the form?